# How to change the link structure of the homepage?

Tags: permalinks, blog, blog-page

There are "your last posts" on the homepage.

Under normal circumstances, the page proceeds as follows: 
http://example.com/page/1
http://example.com/page/2 e.t.c

I want to change this link structure. For example, like http://example.com/image/1. So I want to replace the term "Page" with something else or delete it completely. How do we edit a Wordpress blog perma link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change core files:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse316713_pagination_base_rewrite_rule' );
function wpse316713_pagination_base_rewrite_rule() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'image';
}
```

Go to permalink options page, and press save to flush the rewrite rules, changes should apply afterwards.

Comment: It definitely works! (cache cleared for changes to work)

Thank you. You are great!