# Redirect From Url To Url

Tags: permalinks, pages, redirect

I want to redirect the same directory, but different url structure. The url structure I use: http:example.com/car/cadillac/image/2

I want to direct http: example.com/car/cadillac/image/ url. Because this url is 404. I want to redirect to http: example.com/car/cadillac/

(In fact, the problem comes from the "image" link structure: [How to change the permalink structure of a master page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323035/how-to-change-the-permalink-structure-of-a-master-page)) As an alternative, I thought about the routing rule. But the cpanel 301 redirect is not successful.

**http: example.com/car/cadillac/image/** How can we redirect the URL to **http: example.com/car/cadillac/**  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do is by using [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Head to **Tools > Redirection**.
3. Enter your **Source URL** (example.com/car/cadillac/image/) and
   **Target URL** (http: example.com/car/cadillac/).
4. Finally, click on "Add Redirection" button.